# Is it a good practice loading local json file for unit testing js web request?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I plan to write multiple simulated web request response and store locally as  json. Is it a good practice? I don't use spy like the following because my json file is too long and is not convenient to fit into code

```
it('should send post params in request body', function() {
    var params = { foo: 'bar' };
    var expected = JSON.stringify(params);

    var request = new PassThrough();
    var write = sinon.spy(request, 'write');

    this.request.returns(request);

    api.post(params, function() { });

    assert(write.withArgs(expected).calledOnce);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a unit test is to *quickly* get from

1. a failing test case to
2. the production code at fault

Meaning: you read the test code, and you immediately understand what it is supposed to do. Without the need to scroll through 10 different files (belonging to the "test" side of your source code).

Therefore, the general practice is to write unit tests that are self-contained as much as possible. Because *each* indirection makes it harder for you to get from 1. to 2.

Having said that, you still want to write a human readable unit test. And having "too much" JSON data in your test will quickly diminish readability.

The next best thing then: having that JSON data sitting as file closely to your unit test.

So, long story short: it is not ideal to have your unit tests rely on information *outside* of the test case, but sometimes it is inevitable.